# Множество асинхронных запросов, какие проблемы могут быть?

Tags: java, android, post, retrofit, android-asynctask

Есть задача передать фотографии на специальный ресурс.

Ресурс реализует API для получения фотографии.

Сейчас реализую передачу так: в AsyncTask вызываются запросы на передачу фотографии.Они последовательно, друг за другом отправляются на сервер.

Посетила мысль - сразу создать кучу асинхронных запросов, на каждую фотографию по запросу.

Какие проблемы могут возникнуть? Число фотографий может достигать пары сотен. 
Или может реализовать какой-то специальный сервис по загрузке данных?

Comment: Лучше сервис. Он как раз для такого и предназначен. И AsyncTask лучше вообще не использовать - он устарел и неудобен. В Retrofit и так есть возможность асинхронно запросы слать. А если ещё rxJava прикрутить - вообще красиво получится.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я в принципе так и реализовал. Сервис, внутри AsyncTask, внутри синхронные запросы. Синхронные, чтобы отследить завершение отправки всего пакета. Вопрос, что будет если порядка сотни асинхронных запросов со своими CallBack-ами будет выполняться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как бы Вы ни сделали загрузку на сервер, ширина канала интернета у Вас от этого не изменится.

Поэтому если при последовательной загрузке первый файлы будут доступны на ресурсе сравнительно быстро, то при параллельной придётся подождать. За то разница по времени между одновременно загружаемыми файлами будет меньше. Но, при параллельной загрузке большого количества файлов придётся их загружать партиями, иначе процесс загрузки будет длиться неприемлемо долго.

Загрузку в любом случае лучше всего сделать в фоновом режиме через сервис. От `AsyncTask` лучше уходить, т.к. он на это не рассчитан и с ним будет очень много проблем.